# 1 form with 1 input field and 2 buttons; need input name changed depending on which button is used

Tags: javascript, forms, button, field

I need to have a form with a single input field, and two buttons.

The tricky part is I need the input field **name** changed depending on which button is pressed.

```
<FORM name="Form1" id="num_colis" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="text" name="abc OR xyz" value="">
<INPUT type="button" value="Colissimo" onclick="return OnButton1();">
<INPUT type="button" value="CSUIVI" onclick="return OnButton2();">
</FORM>
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site1.fr/suivi"    
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site2.fr/suivi"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

For this to work, I would need : "INPUT TYPE="text" name="abc" to be used when button1 is pressed, and similarly "INPUT TYPE="text" name="xyz" to be used when button2 is pressed.

I looked everywhere for a solution to no avail, is there a javascript solution or trick to achieve this?

Comment: What are your trying to actually achieve with it? Maybe there is another way to do what you want. Changing the names of input fields doesn't sound like the "good way".

Answer (score 1):

using Pure **JavaScript**

set **id**  attribute to input

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="textField" value="">


function OnButton1()
{
    document.getElementById('textField').name = 'abc';
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site1.fr/suivi"
    document.Form1.submit(); // Submit the page

}
function OnButton2()
{
    document.getElementById('textField').name = 'xyz';
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site2.fr/suivi"
    document.Form1.submit(); // Submit the page

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign an id to the text field and change the name of the id when the function is being run.
Here I have assigned an id to the input which is "myInput" and when you click on the button, the function is changing the name of the field where the id of the field is "myInput".

```
<FORM name="Form1" id="num_colis" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="myInput" name="abc OR xyz" value="">
<INPUT type="button" value="Colissimo" onclick="return OnButton1();">
<INPUT type="button" value="CSUIVI" onclick="return OnButton2();">
</FORM>
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.getElementById('myInput').name='abc';
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site1.fr/suivi"    
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.getElementById('myInput').name='xyz';
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site2.fr/suivi"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a hidden input field?

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="abc_or_xyz" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="text" name="text" value="">
```

...

```
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site1.fr/suivi";    
    document.Form1.abc_or_xyz.value = "abc";
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "http://www.site2.fr/suivi";
    document.Form1.abc_or_xyz.value = "xyz";
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
```

Server side you check the request attribute `abc_or_xyz`, which makes it possible to interpret request attribute `text` differently.

Comment: Thank you very much asgoth. I needed the name changed, not the value though, so just changed to document.Form1.abc_or_xyz.name and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Swap</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(){
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("name", "abc");
}
function xyv(){
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("name", "xyv");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="Form1" id="num_colis" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" id="name" name="abc OR xyz" value="">
    <INPUT type="button" id="button1" value="Colissimo" onclick="abc()">
    <INPUT type="button" id="button2" value="CSUIVI" onclick="xyv()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

using jquery

```
<FORM name="Form1" id="num_colis" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="name" name="abc OR xyz" value="">
<INPUT type="button" id="button1" value="Colissimo">
<INPUT type="button" id="button2" value="CSUIVI">
</FORM>
<script language="Javascript">
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('#name').attr('name', 'abc');
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
  $('#name').attr('name', 'xyz');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe it, a response so fast! Trying it now, thank you soo much!